# closing saveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i have problem with closing saveFileDialog. when i click'cancel' window appears once again. here is my code:

```
        private void SaveAsItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "untitled";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "CANCEL";
            issaved = false;
        }
        else
        {
            issaved = true;
            SaveFile.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
        }
        SaveFile.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` twice, once to show it and once to get the result. You only need to call it once. Remove the line that says, `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();` by itself, you're already doing that inside the `if` condition.

Edit: you'll also need to move all the `FileStream` operations inside of the else block for it to work properly after you remove that line. Here is my edited version:

```
    private void SaveAsItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "untitled";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt";
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "CANCEL";
        issaved = false;
    }
    else
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        issaved = true;
        SaveFile.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
        SaveFile.Close();
    }
}
```

You could also skip the `FileStream` altogether an just do a `File.WriteAlltext(saveFileDialog1.FileName, richTextBox1.Text)`.

Comment: Oops... sorry. In all my editing I forgot to edit the thing that actually mattered. I edited it again. Try it now.

Comment: @luksan I was about to edit your code. I saw the mistake.. :)